# What is a correct usage of smart/dumb component pattern?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a  `DropdownFilter` presentational component that I want to reuse for multiple different filters.

```
const DropdownFilter: React.FC<DropdownFilterProps> = ({
  filterValue,
  filterOptions,
  onClickHandler,
}) => {
  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle id="dropdown">{filterValue}</Dropdown.Toggle>
      <Dropdown.Menu>
        {filterOptions.map((option, i) => (
          <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => onClickHandler(option)} key={i}>
            {option}
          </Dropdown.Item>
        ))}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default DropDownFilter;
```

The state of each filter is controlled by a `filterReducer` in `Redux`. Does that mean that I have to create several container components to get the data for each separate filter?

```
const StatusFilterContainer: React.FC = () => {
  const statusFilterValue = useSelector(getStatusFilterValue);
  const statusFilterOptions = ["Show All", "Pending", "Completed", "Cancelled"];

  const onStatusFilterChange = (filterValue: string): void => {
    dispatch(setStatusFilterValue(filterValue));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DropDownFilter
        onClickHandler={onStatusFilterChange}
        filterOptions={statusFilterOptions}
        filterValue={statusFilterValue}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default StatusFilterContainer;
```

```
const TypeFilterContainer: React.FC = () => {
  const typeFilterValue = useSelector(getTypeFilterValue);
  const typeFilterOptions = ["Show All", "Refill", "Withdrawal"];

  const onStatusFilterChange = (filterValue: string): void => {
    dispatch(setTypeFilterValue(filterValue));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DropDownFilter
        onClickHandler={onStatusFilterChange}
        filterOptions={typeFilterOptions}
        filterValue={typeFilterValue}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default TypeFilterContainer;
```

Comment: I see a lot of code repetition, not very DRY. It may be better to abstract your filter components into a single "abstract" filter/dropdown component that uses the props to specify the selector and dispatch functions, and options.

Comment: That was my concern but I don't really understand how to implement that kind of abstraction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is a correct usage of smart/dumb component pattern?

IMO the correct usage is generally to limit the scope of state and logic  as much as possible, only exposing out state and mutators on the API when necessary (i.e. [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)). There is also the consideration of separations of concerns. For example, the value of some input field of a form submitted to a backend isn't really the concern of the entire app, so keeping it in component state is fine, but something like an authenticated user *could* be a concern for any component in the app, so lift it up.

**Repetitive WET (Write Everything Twice) code:**

Creating a more DRY solution by converting the duplicated logic is rather straight forward. Basically collect what is abstractly identical/common (i.e. using a selector, dispatch action function) and factor out what is different (i.e. the options, the *actual* selector and action), these can be passed as props.

Abstractly this is a component that is provided options to render, selects *some* state, and dispatches *some* action on option change.

```
const FilterContainer: React.FC = ({
  options,
  selectorFn,
  setFilterValueAction,
}) => {
  const filterValue = useSelector(selectorFn);

  const onStatusFilterChange = (filterValue: string): void => {
    dispatch(setFilterValueAction(filterValue));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DropDownFilter
        onClickHandler={onStatusFilterChange}
        filterOptions={options}
        filterValue={filterValue}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Notice now this is very similar to the original `DropDownFilter` component (it's basically just a proxy at this point), we *could* just move the little bit of logic into `DropDownFilter` directly (*or the JSX from, depending on your philosophical bend*).

```
const DropdownFilter: React.FC<DropdownFilterProps> = ({
  filterOptions,
  stateSelector,
  onChangeAction,
}) => {
  const filterValue = useSelector(stateSelector);

  const onStatusFilterChange = (filterValue: string): void => {
    dispatch(onChangeAction(filterValue));
  };

  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle id="dropdown">{filterValue}</Dropdown.Toggle>
      <Dropdown.Menu>
        {filterOptions.map((option, i) => (
          <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => onStatusFilterChange(option)} key={i}>
            {option}
          </Dropdown.Item>
        ))}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};
```

We've now internalized the selector, dispatch, and rendering logic, just need the options, selector to get state, and the action to take when the option changes.

Usage:

```
const StatusFilterContainer: React.FC = () => (
  <DropdownFilter
    filterOptions={["Show All", "Pending", "Completed", "Cancelled"]}
    onChangeAction={setStatusFilterValue}
    stateSelector={getStatusFilterValue}
  />
);

const TypeFilterContainer: React.FC = () => (
  <DropdownFilter
    filterOptions={["Show All", "Refill", "Withdrawal"]}
    onChangeAction={setTypeFilterValue}
    stateSelector={getTypeFilterValue}
  />
);
```

Comment: It definitely looks cleaner that way but do we not violate the main principle of "dumb" components by accessing Redux state and dispatching actions to store from within?

Comment: @АлександрФомин I'm familiar with what many consider "smart" and "dumb" components, but are you specifically referring to the Presentational/Container pattern? Here I'd consider `DropDown` to be the "presentational", or "dumb", component, taking only data to render and callbacks to invoke upon interaction, and `DropdownFilter` to be the "Container", or "smart", component, since it "wires up" external dependencies (state and handlers) to the props of the visual UI component. 
This was/is a good read on the pattern: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0